# Erro de conexão no EXPO

Tags: javascript, node.js, react, react-native, expo

Alguns de vocês, assim como eu, devem ter feito a última Semana Omnistack.

Eu estou tendo um erro ao conectar a rota de Login do meu back-end no meu front-end. Estou usando o `axios` para isso. Quando dou um `yarn start` ou `expo start`a interface do Expo é aberta e eu conecto com o aplicativo no meu celular. A tela de login aparece normalmente, o problema acontece quando eu aperto o botão de login.

**Erro:**

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Network Error]

Stack trace:
  node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:24 in createError
  node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:81:25 in handleError
  node_modules\event-target-shim\lib\event-target.js:172:43 in dispatchEvent
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:580:29 in setReadyState
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:394:25 in __didCompleteResponse
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:190:12 in emit
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:366:47 in __callFunction
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:106:26 in <unknown>
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:314:10 in __guard
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:105:17 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

Eu fiz os testes das rotas com o Insomnia e estão funcionando corretamente, alguém pode ajudar?